# Как собрать все строки из столбца DataTable в переменную

Tags: c#, ado.net

**Имеется**
DataTable(на клиенте):

- pole_1;
- pole_2;
- pole_3.

pole_1 имеет строки:

- str_1;
- str_2;
- str_3.

**ВОПРОС**
Как собрать строки 'pole_1' в переменную в формате "str_1, str_2, str_3"?

Comment: На клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: @A K на клиенте